# Solve using: complete quadratic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$x^2 - x - 20 > 0$$

$$x^2 - x > 20$$

Step 3:

So to complete it, let's use: $1/2$ so it ends up with $x$ as the middle term.

$$x^2 - x + 1/2 > 20 + 1/2$$

Step 4:

But then:

It would be transform to:

$$(x - 1/2)^2 > 20 + 1/2$$

Step 5:

But resolving it, the initial inequation of "Step3" is different:

$$x^2 - 2(x)(1/2) + (-1/2)^2 > 20 + 1/2$$

Giving us:

$$x^2 - x + 1/4 > 20 + 1/2$$

Which is different than:

$$x^2 - x + 1/2 > 20 + 1/2$$

Any hint?

Comment: $x^2-x+1/2\neq (x-1/2)^2=x^2-x+1/4$.

Comment: Step $4$ is false, because $(-1/2)^2=1/4$ and not $1/2$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde 3 or 4? With $1/2$ I get $x$ to have coefficient $1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, yes that's what I say in step 5. I cannot immage another number to complete the equation and set 1 as coefficient for $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way the O.P. started is simpler:
\begin{align*}
x^2-x>20&\iff x^2-x+\frac14=\Bigl(x-\frac12\Bigr)^2>20+\frac14=\frac{81}4\\
&\iff \biggl\lvert x-\frac12\biggr\rvert>\frac92\qquad\text{(taking square roots)}\\
&\iff x>\frac12+\frac92=5\enspace\text{or}\enspace x<\frac12-\frac92=-4
\end{align*}
Hence the set of solutions is $\;(-\infty,-4)\cup(5,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

Given $$\displaystyle x^2-x-20=0\Rightarrow \underbrace{x^2-x+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}-\underbrace{20-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2} =0$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{9}{2}\right)^2>0$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \left[x-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{9}{2}\right]\cdot \left[x-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{9}{2}\right]>0$$

So we get $$(x-5)(x+4)>0\Rightarrow x<-4\cup x>5$$

So our Solution is $$x\in \left(-\infty,-4\right)\cup (5,\infty)$$

Comment: How do you get: $20 - (1/2)^2$ to be $(9/2)^2$? I got = 79/4.

Comment: actually it is $\displaystyle -20-\frac{1}{2^2} = -\frac{81}{4}$

Comment: That is different than $(9/2)^2$.

Comment: $\displaystyle -\frac{81}{4} = -\left(\frac{9}{2}\right)^2$

Comment: Oh my bad. Thanks!